# Repeat entire table in RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Currently in my report showing data in single table.

[image]

But right now I need to split this table in to multiple tables based on department like this :

[image]

[image]

How I can achieve this in rdlc. I am new in rdlc report.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you dont add for each Department a tablix, you just use one tablix and group it by the Department. Go to the bottom of you report design under **RowGroups**. Click on the **(Details)** drop down arrow and select **Add Group > Parent Group** and select your Department. You even can add totals under each grouped department.

If you really want more tablixes you copy paste the same tablix a few times and then add a filter. **Tablix Properties > Filters > Add**, then add your Department filter.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberryshrub.i need to show rows in separate table structure.and i need to render table dynamically.i dont know how many departments exists for each report because of that i cant add tablix in report permanently.

Comment: if i am using row group how can i show the table column headers again.??

Comment: Right click on the left side of the tablix details section (the gray area with 3 lines in it) and chose **Insert Row > Outside Group - Above**.